# Outbound Integration Fails in Maximo

Tags: maximo

We have work order outbound integration from Maximo to an external system. For testing purpose I'm posting the data from Maximo to node-red. The payload is JSON and the following error comes up.
`BMXAA1477E - The connection failed to the HTTP handler for the endpoint. Review the error and server log flies for information to indicate the cause of the issue, for example, incorrect properties in the DefaultHTTPExit.java handler class.    Permission denied: connect`
I'm not sure if this is an issue related to SSL. I tried to post the same JSON from POSTMAN to node-red and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen issues like that be due to SSL versions. You might try following instructions in [this support article from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-can-i-configure-websphere-application-server-ssl-protocol-use-tlsv12-only) on making WebSphere use TLS 1.2.